# Best Model for Graphing Database

Tags: database-design, neo4j

I am trying to learn how to use graphing databases (specifically Neo4j).

I don't know which model would best suite my use and data scenario. Can anyone advise me?

**Scenario:**

I have 3 people that can, on any given day, travel to one of 5 cities or they can choose to remain in the city that they are currently in. I potentially want to know any of the following answers:

- On what day was person 1 in city 2?
- On what day was person 2 in city 1 and traveled to city 2?
- On what day did person 3 not travel, and what city was he/she in?
- Who traveled to city 4 and what days did they travel there?
- Where was person 2 on such-and-such a date?
- The list of questions could go on and on...

**The Question(s):**

Assuming that **person** is a node, what makes more sense?

- A. Make nodes for each **travel_from_city - travel_to_city** combination and use the **date** as a relation
- B. Make nodes for each of the **dates** and use the **travel_from_city - travel_to_city** as a relation

i.e. Either I have, say, 365 (and growing) **date nodes** and a fixed number of **city relations** (one for each city origin - city destination combination). Or I have, a growing number of **date relations** and a fixed number of **city nodes** (one for each city origin - city destination combination).

Are relations more 'expensive' than nodes? Or are nodes more 'expensive' than relations.

Which model would prove to be the most flexible for asking questions I haven't thought of yet?

I appreciate your help and suggestions!

Comment: I'm thinking that neither model is correct and that the person, date and cities should all be nodes, and 'stayed', 'traveled_to' and 'traveled_from' should be simple relations with no 'required' attributes.

Comment: if something is important for your business, it should be a node. So you simply have to extract all the entity of your questions, and modelize them as node (ex: Person, City, Date, Travel)

Comment: I ended up using
    (Person)-[:HAS_DATE]->(City)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:

```
(Person)-[:HAS_DATE]->(City)
```